# why the sum of two variables is insignificant while each of them are?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, regression-coefficients, disaggregation

When I regress stock returns of period $t$ on stock ownership of period $t-1$, the coefficient on this lagged stock ownership is insignificant.

However, when I disaggregate the lagged stock ownership into stock ownership in period $t-2$ plus the change of ownership from period $t-2$ to $t-1$, the coefficients on these two disaggregated are both significantly negative. Since the coefficients of the disaggregated variables have the same sign and are both significant,Thanks!

Comment: If you are relying on the p-values from ordinary least squares regression to assess "significance," be aware that these are wrong because your models, to be consistent, must explicitly suppose the explanatory variables have sizable error terms.  But perhaps you are using a more appropriate way to assess significance: what is it?

Comment: Of the many ways to answer this question: because OLS finds the *optimal* combination of two variables to predict the response. The model: Y = X + W + e1 is a special case of Y = aX + bW + e2 where b and a are any real value. Consider b may be -a.

Comment: @AdamO I interpret "both significantly negative" as meaning $\hat a$ and $\hat b$ are both negative, ruling out your consideration as inconsistent with the data.